# CNN performance results are different in Debug mode and Release mode

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, release-mode, debug-mode

I ran the following code against the appa face dataset (https://chalearnlap.cvc.uab.cat/dataset/26/description/)
https://github.com/yu4u/age-gender-estimation/blob/master/age_estimation/train.py

However, as you can see from the results below, the performance results are different in Debug mode and Release mode (I am using PyCharm). The results in Debug mode are better than those in Release mode.

Why is that so?

release mode result:

```
Epoch 99/100
64/64 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 3.8237 - age_mae: 9.8588
Epoch 99: val_age_mae improved from 10.31055 to 10.26129, saving model to E:\Project\ref_code\face2age_age-gender-estimation-master\age_estimation\..\checkpoints\weights.099-3.875-10.261.hdf5
64/64 [==============================] - 63s 986ms/step - loss: 3.8237 - age_mae: 9.8588 - val_loss: 3.8748 - val_age_mae: 10.2613 - lr: 8.0000e-04
Epoch 100/100
64/64 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 3.8306 - age_mae: 9.9421
Epoch 100: val_age_mae did not improve from 10.26129
64/64 [==============================] - 63s 975ms/step - loss: 3.8306 - age_mae: 9.9421 - val_loss: 3.8752 - val_age_mae: 10.2669 - lr: 8.0000e-04

Process finished with exit code 0
```

debug mode result:

```
Epoch 98/100
64/64 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.7404 - age_mae: 3.1714
Epoch 98: val_age_mae did not improve from 5.98561
64/64 [==============================] - 61s 945ms/step - loss: 2.7404 - age_mae: 3.1714 - val_loss: 3.6023 - val_age_mae: 6.1649 - lr: 8.0000e-04
Epoch 99/100
64/64 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.7362 - age_mae: 3.1317
Epoch 99: val_age_mae did not improve from 5.98561
64/64 [==============================] - 61s 955ms/step - loss: 2.7362 - age_mae: 3.1317 - val_loss: 3.5799 - val_age_mae: 6.1791 - lr: 8.0000e-04
Epoch 100/100
64/64 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.7008 - age_mae: 3.0804
Epoch 100: val_age_mae did not improve from 5.98561
64/64 [==============================] - 62s 956ms/step - loss: 2.7008 - age_mae: 3.0804 - val_loss: 3.5764 - val_age_mae: 6.0456 - lr: 8.0000e-04

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I ran the Python code in debug mode and release mode, and the results were different.